# Working with pop up canvases

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Trying to create a pop up canvas that will pop up when I hit the certain key combination and then it will display images that can be scrolled through using the arrow keys and then closed out with the escape key.  This is all going on top of a canvas that has a map drawn on it that I can use the the arrow keys to move around the map.  Since I'm having many issues with this that are all pretty much interrelated I figured I would just asking them all with one post instead of doing separate posts, it may come in very handy to have all the information in one place for other people as well.

Currently, I have tried several approaches to solve the problem, I do see one other possible option just a couple minutes ago since I finally got online this morning but it didn't seem to want to work.

Question 1: Where do you form the pop up canvas?  In the original

```
def __init__(self, parent):
```

or do you normally wait until the time of the switch over to the pop up to form the pop canvas?  I have tried it both ways and have seen problems with both approaches.  Forming it at the start up causes the pop up to pop up on the screen right from the get go.  I have seen on effbot.org that supposedly using the state='hidden' attribute exists but when I try to use it all I get is an error that says I can only use 'disabled' or 'normal'.

Question 2: So how do you hide the popup until you want to use it, if you create the pop up at the start of the program versus waiting until the pop up key combo is pushed?

I have tried sizing the pop up to 0x0 but I still see single pixel on the screen until I hit the key combo.

I have tried waiting until key combo is hit to bring up the pop up and that works fine until I get ready to change to the second image.

On effbot.org I saw and have tried several different combinations to try to 'disable' without destroying(which I don't want to do) the canvas underneath when the pop up comes up.  The trouble I have is when I go and push an arrow key the underneath canvas still has the focus and it moves the map instead of change the image on the pop up.  I have tried several of the effbot combinations...

```
self.canvas.config(state='disabled')
self.canvaspopup = Canvas(self, width=800, height=614)
self.canvaspopup.pack_propagate(0)
self.canvaspopup.place(x=284,y=52)
self.png = Label(self.canvaspopup)
self.png.pack()             
self.canvaspopup.focus_set()
```

I have also tried

```
self.canvas.bind('<FocusOut>')
self.canvaspopup.bind('<FocusIn>')
```

And still no luck, the underneath canvas still has the focus and I'm still moving the map instead of advancing the image in the pop up.  I am guessing given it was on the Events and Bindings page on effbot.org that I saw FocusIn/Out being talked about that I should put that in the .bind statement and not in the .config.

Question 3: How do I get the pop up to take the focus, pretty much should only need keyboard focus and no mouse focus?

I know I want to keep the pop up handy as I want to be able to click on the underlying map in different locations and have the program go to the internet and pull up data for those locations so the pop up is something that will be used several times throughout any one run of the program.  I know from what I've seen I can use

```
self.canvaspopup.destroy()
```

But this destroys the canvas so I would have to recreate it again.  So if I put the pop up creation at the beginning of the program...I'm screwed and can't recreate it.  Which leads right back to Question 2.

Definitely a mess.  I have most everything working fine, its just the interaction, and knowing the proper way of handling this kind of situation that has me stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `place`, you can use `place_forget` to hide the popup. For the focus, you use `focus_set`.

Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class PopupCanvas(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.parent = parent
        self.text_item=self.create_text(10, 10, anchor="nw")
        self.bind("<Left>", self.handle_left)
        self.bind("<Right>", self.handle_right)
        self.bind("<Escape>", self.hide)

    def handle_left(self, event=None):
        self.itemconfigure(self.text_item, text="You clicked left")

    def handle_right(self, event=None):
        self.itemconfigure(self.text_item, text="You clicked right")

    def show(self, event=None):
        self.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center")
        self.focus_set()

    def hide(self, event=None):
        self.place_forget()
        self.parent.focus_set()

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="Press 'p' to pop up a canvas, <escape> to hide it\n" +
                 "Press left and right arrows when the popup is visible")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
popup = PopupCanvas(canvas, width=200, height=200, background="pink")

label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

canvas.focus_set()
canvas.bind("<p>", popup.show)

root.mainloop()
```